# GO open local postgres connection

Tags: database, postgresql, go

My postgres is running locally on Mac on a port 5432

It has database on it named `test`, and this database has one table in it called `test_table`

I'm trying to connect to it using GO.

Imports:

```
 "database/sql"
 _ "github.com/lib/pq"
```

Main:

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://user:@localhost:5432/test")
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
defer db.Close()

if err2 := db.Ping(); err2 != nil {
 fmt.Println("Failed to keep connection alive")
}

db.QueryRow("INSERT INTO test.test_table (name) VALUES (`something`)) RETURNING id").Scan(&id)

fmt.Println(id)
```

To test the connection I'm running Ping and also try to Insert one line into test_table. But it returns me:

```
Failed to keep connection alive
0
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: What does `err2` contain? You should print that too.

Comment: it told "SSL is not enabled on the server", so I did sslmode=disable and now  Ping goes through. The problem is, it still doesn't add a row into the table. How can I check the list of tables or something like this to make sure that I'm in a right database?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `Exec()` for that?

Comment: QueryRow is correct (due to returning clause)... what error is Scan returning?

Comment: Scan is returning 0 and I don't see any rows added to the test_table

Comment: There seems to be an extra parenthesis in the `INSERT INTO` query after `something`

Comment: also, Scan doesn't return a number.  it returns an error, I'd bet that you are seeing an error about the extra paren.  https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Row.Scan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In situations like these, it pays to go through the following checklist:

- can you connect to the server using the same arguments provided to the go server? I.e. can you run `psql -U user -p 5432 -h localhost test` ?
- are you printing all errors? In the question, `err2` should be printed, as it contains critical information about what's going on. `Scan` also returns an error that is not being saved to a variable or printed. If it were, you might have seen the syntax problem in your query.
- can you you run the query in the SQL shell? (`psql`) If not, fix the query first before continuing.